# How to automatically change text and pictures using a state machine in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a character, "Pepe". My goal is to display Pepe's mood using a textbox for his state (his mood, "happy", "sad", etc.), another textbox for what he says, and an image that shows how he feels. What I want to do is change his current state *with time*. After a certain number of seconds, I want his state to change from "Happy" to "Sad", and then continue to change like a real living animal.   I have four states for Pepe: "Happy", "Sad", "Hungry" and "Angry". I have the JavaScript code below. In the HTML, I included buttons so if Pepe is "Hungry", a button can change Pepe from "Hungry" to "Happy". My problem is that I can't get the images to *automatically* change. I want it to be as random as possible. Any ideas?

```
var thePest

function pestConstructor(state,pepe,petimage,counter)
{

 this.state = state
    this.pepe = pepe
    this.petimage = petimage
    this.counter = counter
}
function startup()
{

 thePest = new pestConstructor("Happy","Hi!",
 "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.141976807.7205/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg",0)

      display(thePest)
      setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)",1000)
}
function display(pest)
{


 var state = pest.state

 if( state == "Angry" ) 
      {
           pest.pepe = "AHHHH!!!"
           pest.petimage = "http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/017/318/angry_pepe.jpg"
      }
      else if( state == "Happy" ) 
      {
           pest.pepe = "Hi!"
           pest.petimage = "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.141976807.7205/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg"
      }
      else if( state == "Hungry" ) 
      {  
           pest.pepe = "FOOD!"
           pest.petimage = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CS5XSd1UkAEfpUv.png"
      }
       else if( state == "Sad" ) 
      {  
           pest.pepe = "I'm Sad"
           pest.petimage = "http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/945/016/648.png"
      }
      else 
      {
          pest.petmood = "Dead"
      }

      document.getElementById("state").value = pest.state
      document.getElementById("pepe").value = pest.pepe
      document.getElementById("petimage").src = pest.petimage
      document.getElementById("counter").value = pest.counter
}
function Simulate(pest)
{

 pest.counter++
 var state = pest.state

      var n = Math.random(pest.state)

      if( state == "Happy" && n < 0.5 ) 
          pest.state = "Hungry"
      else if( state == "Hungry" && n < 0.4 )
          pest.state = "Angry"
      else if( state == "Angry" && n < 0.42 )
          pest.state = "Sad"
      else if( state == "Sad" && n < 0.43 )
          pest.state = "Sleepy"
      else if( state == "Sleepy" && n < 0.3 )
          pest.state = "Dead"

      display(thePest)
      setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)",1000)
}
function Feed(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Hungry" )
          pest.state = "Happy"

         display(thePest)
}
function Love(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Sad" )
          pest.state = "Happy"

         display(thePest)
}
function Mad(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Mad" )
          pest.state = "Happy"

         display(thePest)
}
function Annoy(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Happy" )
          pest.state = "Angry"

         display(thePest)
}
</script>`
```

Comment: `setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)",1000)` Why are there quotes around `Simulate(thePest)` ?

Comment: @Zze Since both `Simulate` and `thePest` are globals it would be no problem (*although bad pattern*). Your code though has a problem in that it will be immediately executed and not wait for the `setTimeout`. For that you will have to wrap it in a function `setTimeout(function(){Simulate(thePest);},1000);`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i see is that you do not ever call the `startup` which fires up the whole process.

---

**Update** without using current state for randomness

```js
var thePest

function pestConstructor(state, pepe, petimage, counter) {

  this.state = state
  this.pepe = pepe
  this.petimage = petimage
  this.counter = counter
}

function startup() {

  thePest = new pestConstructor("Happy", "Hi!",
    "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.141976807.7205/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg", 0)

  display(thePest)
  setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)", 1000)
}

function display(pest) {


  var state = pest.state

  if (state == "Angry") {
    pest.pepe = "AHHHH!!!"
    pest.petimage = "http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/017/318/angry_pepe.jpg"
  } else if (state == "Happy") {
    pest.pepe = "Hi!"
    pest.petimage = "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.141976807.7205/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg"
  } else if (state == "Hungry") {
    pest.pepe = "FOOD!"
    pest.petimage = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CS5XSd1UkAEfpUv.png"
  } else if (state == "Sad") {
    pest.pepe = "I'm Sad"
    pest.petimage = "http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/945/016/648.png"
  } else {
    pest.petmood = "Dead"
  }

  document.getElementById("state").value = pest.state
  document.getElementById("pepe").value = pest.pepe
  document.getElementById("petimage").src = pest.petimage
  document.getElementById("counter").value = pest.counter
}

function Simulate(pest) {

  pest.counter++
    var state = pest.state

  var n = Math.random(pest.state)
  // assuming you want to stop when Dead
  if (pest.state !== "Dead") {
    if (state == "Sleepy" && n < 0.1)
      pest.state = "Dead"
    else if (n < 0.2)
      pest.state = "Hungry"
    else if (n < 0.3)
      pest.state = "Angry"
    else if (n < 0.4)
      pest.state = "Sad"
    else if (n < 0.5)
      pest.state = "Sleepy"

    display(thePest)
    setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)", 1000)
  }
}

function Feed(pest) {

  var state = pest.state

  if (state == "Hungry")
    pest.state = "Happy"

  display(thePest)
}

function Love(pest) {

  var state = pest.state

  if (state == "Sad")
    pest.state = "Happy"

  display(thePest)
}

function Mad(pest) {

  var state = pest.state

  if (state == "Mad")
    pest.state = "Happy"

  display(thePest)
}

function Annoy(pest) {

  var state = pest.state

  if (state == "Happy")
    pest.state = "Angry"

  display(thePest)
}

startup();
```

```html
state: <input id="state"><br> pepe: <input id="pepe"><br> img: <img src="" id="petimage"><br> counter: <input id="counter"><br>
```

Just a heads up: You have no display data for the `Sleepy` state.

Comment: the problem is that it'll change from "Happy" to "Hungry" to "Angry" to "Sad". I want it to be random and I want it to continue changing states instead of stopping at "Sad".

Comment: @AlF updated answer. The thing is you need to not use two checks when randomizing. Your code would only change to another state if both the current state had a specific value and the random number also was in some threshold. So it would only go from one to the other and finish.

Comment: so what would the code be for that? That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @AlF as i mentioned in the previous comment, i have already updated the answer with the relevant fix.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that the only issue was with the setTimeout function was wrapping the callback in double quotes.

```js
var thePest

function pestConstructor(state,pepe,petimage,counter)
{

 this.state = state
    this.pepe = pepe
    this.petimage = petimage
    this.counter = counter
}
function startup()
{

 thePest = new pestConstructor("Happy","Hi!",
 "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.141976807.7205/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg",0)

  display(thePest)
  setTimeout(()=>Simulate(thePest),1000)
}
function display(pest)
{


 var state = pest.state

 if( state == "Angry" ) 
      {
           pest.pepe = "AHHHH!!!"
           pest.petimage = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/ff0000/ffffff"
      }
      else if( state == "Happy" ) 
      {
           pest.pepe = "Hi!"
           pest.petimage = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/00ff00/ffffff"
      }
      else if( state == "Hungry" ) 
      {  
           pest.pepe = "FOOD!"
           pest.petimage = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/fff0ff/000000"
      }
       else if( state == "Sad" ) 
      {  
           pest.pepe = "I'm Sad"
           pest.petimage = "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/0000ff/ffffff"
      }
      else 
      {
          pest.petmood = "Dead"
      }

      console.log(pest.state, pest.pepe, pest.petimage, pest.counter);
      $("img").attr("src",pest.petimage);
}
function Simulate(pest)
{

 pest.counter++
 var state = pest.state

      var n = Math.random(pest.state)

      if( state == "Happy" && n < 0.5 ) 
          pest.state = "Hungry"
      else if( state == "Hungry" && n < 0.4 )
          pest.state = "Angry"
      else if( state == "Angry" && n < 0.42 )
          pest.state = "Sad"
      else if( state == "Sad" && n < 0.43 )
          pest.state = "Sleepy"
      else if( state == "Sleepy" && n < 0.3 )
          pest.state = "Dead"

      display(thePest)
      setTimeout("Simulate(thePest)",1000)
}
function Feed(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Hungry" )
          pest.state = "Happy"

         display(thePest)
}
function Love(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Sad" )
          pest.state = "Happy"

         display(thePest)
}
function Mad(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Mad" )
          pest.state = "Happy"

         display(thePest)
}
function Annoy(pest)
{

 var state = pest.state

  if( state == "Happy" )
          pest.state = "Angry"

         display(thePest)
}

startup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" />
```